# if json solr response is undefined or null in ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, solr

In my project, I'm using solr. In my jsp page, I want to show my solr core's response but some fields are undefined or null. I wrote an ajax call to put response data in the html textbox. I want to check if the field is undefined or null.

```
<script>
function openForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    var salesOrder="\"" + $("#sOrder option:selected").val()+ "\"";
    document.getElementById("sOrder_popup").value=$("#sOrder option:selected").val();
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/StorageCore/select?q=strSO:"
    var URL_MIDDLE="&rows=99999&start=0&wt=json"
    var URL=URL_PREFIX+salesOrder;
    var loc=document.getElementById("location_popup").value;
    $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'json',
        type:'get',
        json : 'json.wrf',
        success : function(data) {
            var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
            var jsonData=JSON.parse(docs);
            if(jsonData[0].strLocation[0]===undefined)
                document.getElementById("location_popup").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("location_popup").value=jsonData[0].strLocation[0];
            //document.getElementById("submitted_popup").value=jsonData[0].strSubmitName[0];

        },
        });
}
function closeForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I wrote if statement in above ajax call but it still gives me this error.

```
Unable to get property 'strLocation' of undefined or null reference
```

Comment: By default Javascript can't make requests to other hosts than the host that originates the request; the Solr server will not be available through your browser by default. Check the developer console in your browser, and the Network tab to see the result of your request. The issue you're seeing is that `jsonData[0]` is undefined, but you're checking `strLocation[0]`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, you're right. I changed it `if(jsonData[0]===undefined)` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error complains that `jsonData[0]` is `undefined`, but you're checking `strLocation[0]`.

```
if (jsonData[0] === undefined)
```

.. or probably better:

```
if (jsonData.length === 0) {
    ...
}
```

Since that actually expresses what you're doing (checking if 0 results were returned), instead of using `undefined` to check if an array index exists.